# Parsing files using PHP which has delimiter \t

Tags: php, csv, xls

IS there a way to parse the file(does not have extension) using PHP. The columns in the files are separated with tab(/t). I need to get each cells in a row with its contents.

I tried following methods

1) Converted(copied and pasted the contents and  saved as a csv file) the file to
   CSV and tried to read each row,but all the row contents came as a single row content.

```
$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("mynew.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        echo "******* <br />";
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            echo $cell . "<br/>";
        }

        echo "******* <br />";
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

2) Tried to read the file by converting(copied and pasted as save as xls) to xls file. Here the entire column in each row as considered as one column. I used PHPExcel library here to read the contents.

Is there any work around to parse the contents of a file that has a no extension using PHP?

Comment: Extensions are completely irrelevant to PHP, it does not use them for anything. Your parsing is wrong, period.

Comment: code or it didn't happen

Comment: @deceze Parsing works fine for well formatted files and I'm sure the code is just fine.

Comment: Is the internal formatting absolutely identical for your "well formatted" files and those without extensions? It does not make sense that you would see any error from files if the only difference is the file name extension.

Comment: There is no error in files except that the problematic file will have a line break in any of its column and the contents in rest of the columns will come in next row(if we opens these files in a word). I checked the delimiter for both the normal and problematic files, and both seems to be same(\t).

Comment: Let's put it this way: file extensions are not the issue here, we have determined that. If you require more help, get off that track, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29138898/edit) and provide more information about the specific files you're having an issue with and the code you're using to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

When reading file you never specify extension of that file. You can do this code to read extensionless file as CSV:

```
$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("testFile", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;

        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            echo $cell . "<br/>";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already. But it is returning the entire csv as a single row and the line breaks are  not identified. This works fine for normal csv files. But I have some files which are having the '\n' and '\r' in some fields of csv and these files are having the issue in sorting out the rows and columns.